# Application run on my machine, and give strange error on others

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, windows

this application runs smoothly on my machine, but when trying to run on others it doesn't appear at all.

after searching the logs i found this

### Source = Application Error

```
Faulting application name: Diamonds 2.1.exe, version: 2.1.1.23755, time stamp: 0x4e426777
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bdfe0
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x000000000000aa7d
Faulting process id: 0x1ad0
Faulting application start time: 0x01cc574ef6707ed5
Faulting application path: C:\Users\Administrator.DEVELOPER\Desktop\EXE\Diamonds 2.1.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 34498134-c342-11e0-8d91-6cf049ab4bd2
```

### Source .NET ERROR

```
Application: Diamonds 2.1.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
Stack:
   at Diamonds.Program.Main(System.String[])
```

the application was running normally, i didn't do any new modifications other than splitting some function to a new dll library.

Any Ideas ??

Comment: Have you copied the new assemblies to the other machine too?

Comment: David's idea is good - but we really just can guess what the problem is without any source code.

Comment: Also, are you sure that the other machines all have the same version of .net and windows? It looks like a problem with the environment.

Comment: @David, yes i copied all the assemblies to the target machine, and it is the same specs (Windows 7 x64 with .NET 4.0.x)

Comment: @Daniel, the application source code, is (huge), and i cannot expect where is the problem to let you see it...

Comment: what i'm trying right now is to try it on another development machine, I'll let you know if i found something

Comment: @Mustafa: Simply include some logging, so you know the place where the exception originates.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered this issue in a Windows form App I created. Apparently there is a plethora of issues that can cause this. In my case you could open the Task Manager, click the application, see it open in the task manager, and immediately close. The only way to see what the issue was, was to look at the event viewer and find the error.

The first is **dependencies**. Like mentioned above, ensure all required .dlls are included and that you have the required framework(s) installed.

Second **KERNELBASE.dll can become corrupted**. To ensure that is not the case you can run the System File checker. Instructions can be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833

Third, is my case. I had a method running in the constructor of Program.cs which is the first thing instantiated when you start a windows form app. I had a bug in code that was **causing an exception before any exception handling was created**. To fix the problem I moved the code to a point after I create an unhandled exception method as such:

`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);`

in my forms constructor. Now the program would start and actually throw an error. I then just had to fix the bug in my code.

I hope this can help you or anyone else out there.

Comment: the problem has been solved, but i don't remember exact cause for that, but I re-install the dontnet framework 4.x and it works fine :)

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad you got that figured out. I added this in hopes it would help someone else later down the road.

Answer (score 1):

If the other machine do not have  Microsoft .NET Framework 4 install it http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17718 . if it depends on c++ assembly you should also check out Visual C++ Redistributable  http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555

Comment: the target machines have .net version and the application was working days ago .

Comment: It happens to me once because of a windows update... I then installed the Visual C++ Redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a problem with the client environment (version of .NET, OS, etc.) you can confirm that by changing your application to do nothing but end, or maybe show a 'hello, client' messagebox.

Comment: yes, I tried this already, but the application don't even start up in the processes :(

Comment: then the problem isn't with your application, it's with the client environments having the required .NET framework files installed